# Automatize checking if a link is live using python

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I need to often manually check if some links are live. To avoid this I would like to write a small script that just returns the https status of all the links so I can immediately see any 404s. Problem is I have no idea what i'm doing I just know it should be possible :D

I tried to do this with a tester page using python's requests and I get the following error

```
import requests

requests.get('https://exp04.zih.tu-dresden.de/')

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='exp04.zih.tu-dresden.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

I understand the individual words of the error message but now nothign about server/client stuff. How do I return the status code for this page?

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests

requests.get('https://exp04.zih.tu-dresden.de/', verify=False)
```

Just ignore the SSL certificate verifying.